# AWS S3 Object Expiration Less Than 24 Hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The built in Object Expiration is 1 day (plus the time to next midnight UTC).  Is there a mechanism to do this at a more frequent basis?  Given it appears that AWS does this across the board at midnight UTC then it's likely there would need to be another mechanism to delete objects sooner.  We're looking for something in the 6-8 hour time frame.  What other options if any would there be?

Thank you

Comment: Your impressions are correct, although it's not precisely "at" midnight UTC that policy rules get acted on.  It's technically "not before" ("any time after") midnight UTC, so with expiration of 1 day, an object created at 01:00:00 today would persist for 47 hours minimum.  Note also that when an object expires, billing stops, but the object doesn't necessarily disappear right away -- lifecycle operations are a background process.  If you will explain your motivation for such short lifecycles, perhaps there is a workaround that makes sense, either by purging or making otherwise inaccessible.

Comment: Great information Michael.  Our use case is simply that we maintain a transient process of 3rd party data and would like to not have it w/in our systems for much longer than is necessary.

Comment: Exactly the same problem. Side-effect of the long time duration is lowering objects's search speed in the bucket. If you have a bucket which is filled quickly in a day, your object search speed in this bucket is becoming low since you need to paginate per 1000 object. Also, it would be very bad if you need to check object's content... Object deletion can be done with a scheduled lambda but I don't want to implement such a feature externally, this should be built-in.

Answer (score 4):

If 12 hours is an acceptable upper bound, then you can setup an S3 event notification to post a message to an SNS topic that has an SQS queue subscribed to the topic with a visibility timeout of the 6-8 hours you're looking for.

[image: diagram]